# Unix shell to prompt user for filename

Tags: shell, unix

please pardon since I am a UNIX beginner.

I wanna write a shell script that can ask user type in the filename and output the number of lines in that file, here is my code:

```
echo "Pls enter your filename:"
read filename
result=wc -l $filename

echo "Your file has $result lines"
```

However, I couldn't get it working since it complains about the identifier "filename". Could experts help?Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That works fine, at least in `bash`. Well, the `read` works fine. However, the assignment to `result` should probably be:

```
result=$(wc -l $filename)
```

but, since that command outputs both the line count *and* the filename, you might want to change it a little to just get the line count, something like:

```
result=$(cat $filename | wc -l)
```

or:

```
result=$(wc -l <$filename)
```

The command you have:

```
result=wc -l $filename
```

will set `result` to the literal `wc`, then try to execute the `-l` command.

For example, the following five-line script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Pls enter your filename:"
read filename
result=$(cat $filename | wc -l)
echo "Your file has $result lines"
```

will, when run and given its name as input, produce the following:

```
Your file has 5 lines
```

---

If you're *not* using `bash`, you need to specify which shell you are using. Different shells have different ways of doing things.

Comment: To get wc to print just the number, `wc -l < $filename` appears more elegant than `cat`

Comment: @glennjackman: You don't need the STDIN redirect -- `wc -l $filename` does the trick too :).

Comment: @jmdeldin, the problem with the is the output of `wc -l infile` is `12345 infile` - it contains the input file name as well. If you just want the number, you can post-process that with something like `awk` (another process), or remove the file name by using stdin (`cat infile | wc ...`, another process, or `< infile` at no extra processes).

Comment: @paxdiablo: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Mental shell scripting...not so effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate wc -l $filename , you have t do:

```
result=$(wc -l $filename)
```

Otherwise, with result=wc -l $filename, bash will assign wc to result, and interpret the next word(-l) as a command to run.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
echo "Pls enter your filename:" 
read filename 
result=`wc -l $filename | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d' '`

echo "Your file has $result lines"
```